# Submenu opened problem

Tags: php, menus, sub-menu

I am trying to fix a problem with a submenu.
I have coded (as you can see on jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/8899x/87/ ) my horizontal menu and the submenu. I would like to leave the submenu opened when I am in the selected child page; for example if I click on "Gallery -> Photogallery 1", I'd like that the submenu and the "Photogallery 1" will stay opened and highlighted. Obvious the same if I click on "Photogallery 2" and so on.

Any help please?

**UPDATED**:
Here is the example of my header.php:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html <?php language_attributes(); ?>>
<head>
<meta charset="<?php bloginfo( 'charset' ); ?>" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=0.1, maximum-scale=1.0"/>
<title><?php
global $page, $paged;

wp_title( '|', true, 'right' );

// Add the blog name.
bloginfo( 'name' );

// Add the blog description for the home/front page.
$site_description = get_bloginfo( 'description', 'display' );
if ( $site_description && ( is_home() || is_front_page() ) )
    echo " | $site_description";

// Add a page number if necessary:
if ( $paged >= 2 || $page >= 2 )
    echo ' | ' . sprintf( __( 'Page %s', '_s' ), max( $paged, $page ) );

?></title>

<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:800,400,600,700' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.2.js"></script>

<link rel="shortcut icon" href="<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/favicon.ico" type="image/vnd.microsoft.icon"/>
<link rel="icon" href="<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/favicon.ico" type="image/x-ico"/>

<!--[if lt IE 9]>
<script src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/js/html5.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<![endif]-->


<?php wp_head(); ?>

</head>

<body <?php body_class(); ?>>

<div id="wrapper" class="container">

<ul id="navbar">
    <li><a href="<?php bloginfo('url') ?>">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="<?php bloginfo('url') ?>/?page_id=258"
        <?php 
        if ( is_page('258') || is_page('300') || ( !is_home() && in_category('5')) || ( !is_home() && in_category('58')) )
        {
         echo " class=\"selected\"";
        }
        ?>>Gallery</a>
            <ul>
            <li><a href="<?php bloginfo('url') ?>/?page_id=258">Photogallery 1</a></li>
            <li><a href="<?php bloginfo('url') ?>/?p=256">Photogallery 2</a></li>
            <li><a href="<?php bloginfo('url') ?>/?page_id=300">Photogallery 3</a></li>
            </ul>
            </li>
    <li><a href="events.php">Events</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Blog</a>
        <ul class="submenu">
           <li><a href="personal.php">Personal</a></li>
           <li><a href="dev.php">Dev</a></li>
        </ul> 
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">About</a>
        <ul class="submenu">
           <li><a href="page1.php">Page 1</a></li>
           <li><a href="page2.php">Page 2</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>​

<div class="clear"></div>

<div id="main">
```

And some lines of the singlecustompage.php:

```
<?php get_header(); ?>

<div id="full-content">
```

Comment: this is a css question, not WordPress

Comment: But this menu is for wordpress!! I putted it in the header and I do not know how can I manage the dynamic pages on WP when I change the page.

Comment: don't use static markup, use WordPress [Navigation Menus](http://codex.wordpress.org/Navigation_Menus).

Comment: I will try, thank you.
But I think that I will ask here again for some help.

Answer (score 0):

Within a WordPress framework, you can do this with a combination of [`body_class`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/body_class) and CSS. [`body_class`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/body_class) will echo classes into the `<body>` tag, including a `page-parent` class, which you can then use to control your elements. Without seeing your actual WordPress page, I can't give you the necessary CSS.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, I added the code of my header.php and the start of a custom page. Hope in some help.